# How do I add a line between 2 Divs

Tags: css, html

I am having problem adding a line between 2 DIVs of the content area (the big image in the centre) and the Poll.

Any help is welcomed, please.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want a line over the entire length of the page? Just the length of the poll? Right in-between the 2 or closer to one or the other?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)... **NO!**

Comment: @nzall I want a line in the middle of the 2 divs, spanning only in the middle of the contents, and not from the start of the div  till the end of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you `#main1` CSS to:

```
#main1 {        
    border-right: 2px solid #666666;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Unless you need the `background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #666666;`, then you will have to do something different with the `padding-right` attribute.

You can change the width/border style/colour to whatever you need.

Comment: That is what it is doing isn't it? However tall your `main1` div is how long the line will be